# What's dconf value for Right Alt?

Tags: gnome, dconf

I'm trying to change my keybinding for switching input sources.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/input-sources/xkb-options "['grp:ralt','grp_led:scroll']"
```

grp:ralt isn't working, what would be the working one?

Comment: `'grp:toggle'` try this ne

Answer (score 0):

`'grp:toggle'` is the answer as `UnKNOWn` suggested in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292269/whats-dconf-value-for-right-alt#comment2194199_1292269).